# 2 issues: Call to undefined function and no writes to database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple class that is causing me some problems. There are 2 problems. I haven't linked my html file, just the class. When I need to use my insert function, it says it is undefined. Also, even if I manually try to insert something into the database, nothing happens.

mysql_connect("come", "at", "me") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("bro") or die(mysql_error());

```
class Update
{

    public $input;

    public function assignCheck($postRequest)
    {
        if(isset($_POST[$postRequest]))
        {
            $this->input = $_POST[$postRequest];
            insert($postRequest);
            return $this->input;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function insert($insertRequest)
    {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO updates (update) VALUE ($insertRequest)");
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "manually"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to call your insert function, you have to use `$this->insert($postRequest)` in your if statement of `assignCheck` function

Answer (score 0):

Within a class you call methods with the pseudo variable

```
$this
```

So:

```
if(isset($_POST[$postRequest]))
{
    $this->input = $_POST[$postRequest];
    $this->insert($postRequest);
    return $this->input;
}
```